# Select active actionbar tab on Visual Studio Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

i have actionbar with some tabs, i don't know how to make "Motorcycle" or "Animals" tab on default (without change the order of the tabs). I'm using VS Xamarin.Android to build android apps.

here is my codes :

```
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        ActionBar.Tab tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText("Animals");
        tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.tab1_icon);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
                               //blalblabla
                           }
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);

tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(Motorcycle);
        tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.tab2_icon);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
                               // blablabla
                           }
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);

        tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(Cars);
        tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.tab2_icon);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
                               // blablabla
                           }
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use [`ActionBar.SelectTab(tab)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#selectTab(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab)).

For example:

```
        tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText("Motorcycle");
        tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.tab2_icon);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // blablabla
        };
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
        ActionBar.SelectTab(tab);
```

Comment: @neneo Does this help you?

Comment: it works!
but i faced new problem, inside TabSelected there are some async process, when i SelectTab(tab) trigerred the await process not awaited and return null value from async process

Comment: @neneo Could you mark this reply as the answer and start a new question for your new issue with some more detail, I will keep following to it.